# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString and NameValueCollection in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, namespaces, using

I'm having some trouble using the HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string) in a windows 8 app
I'm just using this line

```
NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(result);
```

And the problem is that the parts "NameValueCollection" and "HttpUtility" are underlined in red, as if Visual Studio couldn't find them (that's what the error says)
But I don't know which namespaces I should use !

I tried

```
using System.Collections.Specialized ; //for NamevalueCollection
using System.Web ; //for HttpUtility
```

For the first one, it doesn't seem to work as the import is successful but my "NameValueCollection" is still underlined and for the second one, VS considers it as an error and my "using" is underlined...
Thanks

Comment: It's a mistake I made in my question but in my code it is a capital W and still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with this:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;

namespace Test   
{
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            NameValueCollection foo = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("data");
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to reference the `System.Web.dll` and `System.dll`

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**UPDATE**

Since OP's question is about windows phone (which  doesn't have System.Web), an alternative is found here:

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString and NameValueCollection in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807472/httputility-parsequerystring-and-namevaluecollection-in-windows-phone-8/23807817#23807817)

Comment: It might be the references that are missing indeed but how do I reference those dlls ?

Comment: @FlorianChampoussin: in VS 2013: under menu: PROJECT -> Add reference.

Comment: @FlorianChampoussin: Or right click `References` under your project in the `Solution Explorer` (again VS 2013)

Comment: Tried that but I can't find them
Sorry if my questions seem foolish, I'm new to C# and Windows phone developpment EDIT : I can find the references explorer but not the web reference inside the explorer

Comment: @FlorianChampoussin: no problem. Which visual studio version are you using?

Comment: @FlorianChampoussin: no, I don't think so. You mentioned windows phone. The .NET libraries for phone are different then for desktop. You'll need to find an equivalent for the function. Hold on, I'll do a search for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54209/discussion-between-stefan-and-florian-champoussin).